# Url rewrite to lower case

Tags: url-rewriting

I already have the following code in my web.config which does pretty much what I want.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mysite.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{MapSSL:{HTTPS}}www.mysite.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="MapSSL" defaultValue="OFF">
      <add key="ON" value="https://" />
      <add key="OFF" value="http://" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

There is just one element missing from what I can see. The query element of the url will remain as is - mixed/upper case - how can I ensure all of the url is lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a lowercase rule.

```
<rule name="LowerCaseRule" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
  <matchurl="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>
  <actiontype="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}"/>
</rule>
```

its part of default template, Under **Search Engine Optimization (SEO)** template, select **Enforce lowercase URLs**